# Rails: .where method to find a record that contains name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Currently I'm able to add up the current_user's savings accounts with this in the controller:

```
@savings = Account.where(user_id: current_user, accounttype: 'Savings').sum(&:value)
```

What I'd like to do is within this subset of data, also look for the current_user's savings accounts where **:name = "Ally Bank" OR "GE Capital Bank" OR "Barclays" OR ...**

Is there a way to also add a :name contains onto this .where method? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.where(name: ['Ally Bank', 'Capital Bank', 'Barclays'])
```

This will use the sql `IN` clause.

Comment: How would I do .where(name_is_not: ['Ally Bank', ...] for the other query?

Comment: since rails 4 you can simply use `.where.not(:name => ['Ally Bank', ...])